# make selenium browser "headless" when its started

Tags: python, c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

in my case, im using selenium to make something automatic for my user
but at first, my user need to login to the target site by scanning QR-Code in site login page
so i make my browser in maximized and show the site to user by   `driver.GoToUrl("site.com/login")` and i check if user logged in
after user login i need to make chrome headless and do my automation on site.
i know i can set headless as `options.AddArgument("--headless")`  but it make browser start headless and user does not see login page to scan QR-Code
is there any solution to make browser headless after it created and showed login page to user?

if its impossible, help me how to start browser headless before create it but show the QR-Code to my user in another window(sometimes QR-Code change after few second so i thing we cant make screenshot and show the screenshot to user in second window)